# dataTables .row( ) is not a function servers side processing row details

Tags: jquery, function, datatables, row

```
 function format ( d ) {
return 'Full name: <br>'+
       'Salary:<br>'+
       'The child row can contain any data you wish, including links, images, inner     tables etc.';
  }

 $(function() {
 var dtable = $('#table_echipamente').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "inc/table_echipamente.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          "details-control",
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        { "data": "beneficiar" },
        { "data": "distribuit" },
        { "data": "data_distribuit" },
        { "data": "denumire" },
        { "data": "nr_inventar_nou" },
        { "data": "nr_inventar_vechi" },
        { "data": "gestionar" },
        { "data": "observatii" },
        { "data": "optiuni" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]

  });

  // Array to track the ids of the details displayed rows
  var detailRows = [];

  $('#table_echipamente tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td:first-child', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = dtable.row( tr );
    var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        tr.removeClass( 'details' );
        row.child.hide();

        // Remove from the 'open' array
        detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
    } else {
        tr.addClass( 'details' );
        row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();

        // Add to the 'open' array
        if ( idx === -1 ) {
            detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
        }
    }
   } );

  // On each draw, loop over the `detailRows` array and show any child rows
  dtable.on( 'draw', function () {
    $.each( detailRows, function ( i, id ) {
        $('#'+id+' td:first-child').trigger( 'click' );
      } );
  } );



  } );
```

i get the following error when i click on the open button:

> TypeError: dtable.rows is not a function

What am i doing wrong? i followed the example on the official site. I can't find a similar problem so it is very weird.

Comment: Have you included `dataTable` plugin?

Comment: Yes i did include the plugin, the table shows fine the problem is that row details is not working

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had same problem and just got it solved through an answer on stack overflow. Use `DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()`. Method `row().child()` will not work with `dataTable()`. So you will have:

`var dtable = $('#table_echipamente').DataTable( {})`

instead of

```
var dtable = $('#table_echipamente').dataTable( {})
```

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem, based on above comment, I tried to change 'dataTable' to 'DataTable'.  But it now gives error - "DataTable.fnDestroy is not a function"  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906217/getting-error-typeerror-datatable-fndestroy-is-not-a-function
Please help!

Comment: Hi, yes it will give that error because DataTable does not have that method (fnDestroy) anymore, you need to check the API for what to use, can't remember it offhand.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. Make sure that the data table version is 1.10 or above