# table.row is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement row details in my [datatables](http://datatables.net) just like this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

When I click on the show more image of my table, I get an error in my firebug console saying:

```
TypeError: oTable.row is not a function
var row = oTable.row(tr);
```

Here is also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gLqgL7m/) of my code that generates this error.

As i understand it, the `row()` function of my datatables is not found. But i don't get it... I use the latest datatables version with jquery version 1.11.1 (and not 1.11.0 as shown in fiddle) which is what is used in the example also(on datatables website).

I am stuck... Anyone has any idea why I get this error?

Thanks a lot

Comment: probable duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510679/datatables-row-is-not-a-function-servers-side-proccessing-row-details

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I don't know what is the difference between `dataTable` and `DataTable` functions, but your code worked when I initialized the data table using the second function.

```
 oTable = $('#tblCasesMain').DataTable({ ...
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gLqgL7m/8/), which only gives an error on `format` function which is not defined.

Note: I have changed that function name as per [this example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html).

**Update:**
I have done a bit of research and got the answer. Take a look at the *Upgrade note* [here](http://www.datatables.net/manual/installation#Initialising-DataTables) which says the following:

> If you are upgrading from DataTables 1.9 or earlier, you might notice that a capital D is used to initialise the DataTable here. *$().DataTable() returns a **DataTables API instance***, while *$().dataTable() will also initialise a DataTable, but returns a **jQuery object.***

Answer (score 62):

There is not need to use `.DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()`

Simply append `.api()`. It will return the object that defines the required `row()` method.

e.g.: `var row = oTable.api().row(tr);`

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, i had same problem  @U. Kadner

Comment: Thanks for making clear, that `DataTables()` is something like a wrapper for `dataTables()`.

Comment: @U. Kadner, great answer that I couldn't find by googling. Any links that I can reference?

Answer (score 5):

If the above answers don't work in your case, try below alternate.

```
var row = $('#tblSample').DataTable().row(tr);
```

Instead of

```
var oTable =  $('#tblSample').dataTable( {
    //Code
 });
var row = oTable.row(tr);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you haven't  mention `Function`

Check Update Working Link http://jsfiddle.net/2gLqgL7m/7/

Answer (score 1):

Update `dataTable()` wuth `DataTable()` No need to use .dataTable()

Use `.DataTable()`

Example :

```
oTable = jQuery('#tblCasesMain').DataTable({ ...
```