# Getting error - TypeError: DataTable.fnDestroy is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have following code that is using data table

```
Contact.dataTable = $('#table').dataTable( {
.............
},
 $('#table tbody').on('click', '.position', function () {
            var row = this.parentElement;
             var data = Contact.dataTable.row(row).data();
...
}
```

Since above code was giving error `"TypeError: Contact.dataTable.row is not a function"`, I have changed every ***`dataTable`*** to ***`DataTable`***. But now it gives error `"TypeError: Contact.DataTable.fnDestroy is not a function"`.

Below is the code that gives error

```
Contact.DataTable = $('#table').DataTable( {
    .............
    },
     $('#table tbody').on('click', '.position', function () {
                var row = this.parentElement;
                 var data = Contact.DataTable.row(row).data();
    ...
    }

if('DataTable' in Contact) {
            Contact.DataTable.fnDestroy();
}
```

Anyone please help!

Comment: Uhm, `Contact.dataTable !== Contact.DataTable`, you seem to still be working with two different things ?

Comment: No, when I use Contact.dataTable -> it gives me error like Contact.dataTable.row is not a function. So I replaced every instances of dataTable with DataTable - and it now gives error - fnDestroy is not a function

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be the difference between...

_table = jQuery('table#fp-table-table').dataTable(); // .fnDestroy() works
and

_table = jQuery('table#fp-table-table').DataTable(); // .fnDestroy() doesn't work
DataTable seems to be for API calls back into the object and dataTable seems to be the intialisation method.

In my project I had changed the initialisation to use DataTable instead of dataTable to perform a filtering task. After this my AJAX reloads would throw the 'undefined' error, so I changed it back... i esta.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207147/datatable-vs-datatable-why-is-there-a-difference-and-how-do-i-make-them-w) - it talks about the difference between `.DataTable()` and `.dataTable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var Contact = $('#table').DataTable` at the top and then use it Like `Contact.fnDestroy()` It worked For me so give it  try